# Does anyone have information about Piquet and Calitet (chemists)?

Tags: terminology, reference-request

I was given a set of names of chemists to research and one of them was actually a duo that I understand to have been French chemists (at least their last names suggest it). I have queried and queried not simply Google, but also academic databases (Wiley, ProQuest, Elsevier, etc.), yet I've found nothing.

I believe I am spelling the names correctly, but for clarity, phonetic expression of their surnames is:

> "*PEA-ket* and *CAL-ee-TET*"

Hath anyone information on these names within chemistry (or similar natural science discipline)? It would allow me to end a nearly two month search – one way or another.

Most appreciative for any corrections if I have erred in spelling, nation of origin, etc.

Comment: Maybe it is not "Piquet" but "Picquet" (sounds for an English speaker very similar) as here http://www.icmub.fr/185-membres?r=185&action=view&id=17 -- organic chemistry?  or even Picqué / Picque like https://fr.linkedin.com/in/eric-picque-20012342?  Similar on Calité. In which context the names were given to you, may  some information be added (time / location / field of chemistry/history of science)?  Needn't be French, nor living / working in a French speaking country (Canada, Belgium, Switzerland, non-European countries, etc.), either (moving,  maiden / family name).

Answer (score 1):

Can you exclude spelling errors? If not, there is

- *Amé Pictet*, known from the Pictet-Spengler cyclization.
- *Claude Piguet*, an inorganic chemist at the University of Geneva.

Both were/are is Swiss, not French.

However, the second name does not ring a bell for me.